# Is the range of a FilterQuery inclusive up to ToBlock?

Tags: go-ethereum, events

I'm looking to use this [function](https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient#Client.FilterLogs):

```
func (ec *Client) FilterLogs(ctx context.Context, q ethereum.FilterQuery) ([]types.Log, error)
```

but I'm unsure if the range of the [FilterQuery](https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum#FilterQuery) is inclusive or exclusive of `ToBlock`:

```
type FilterQuery struct {
    FromBlock *big.Int         // beginning of the queried range, nil means genesis block
    ToBlock   *big.Int         // end of the range, nil means latest block
 ...
}
```

I'm unsure if "end of the range" is inclusive or exclusive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I demonstrated it's **inclusive**. Here's the experiment I came up with to test this, running against a local geth blockchain:

```
ethLogs, err := client.FilterLogs(context.Background(), ethereum.FilterQuery{
        FromBlock: big.NewInt(10),
        ToBlock:   big.NewInt(11),
        Addresses: []common.Address{address},
    })
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

for _, ethLog := range ethLogs {
    log.Infof("Processed events from block %v", ethLog.BlockNumber)
}
```

The logs show that both blocks 10 and 11 are processed.

> INFO[2019-12-31 12:02:00.736624+0900] Processed events from block 10
>   INFO[2019-12-31 12:02:00.736643+0900] Processed events from block 10
>   INFO[2019-12-31 12:02:00.736650+0900] Processed events from block 11
>   INFO[2019-12-31 12:02:00.736655+0900] Processed events from block 11
>   INFO[2019-12-31 12:02:00.736660+0900] Processed events from block 11

Comment: Yep. I saw the source code too and check that are inclusive. 
// FilterQuery
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/filters/api.go

FilterQuery use NewRangeFilter:
// NewRangeFilter 
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/filters/filter.go

Answer (score 1):

Both parameters are **inclusive**. 
You could try with just a block:

```
query := ethereum.FilterQuery{
  FromBlock: big.NewInt(133420),
  ToBlock:   big.NewInt(133420),
  Addresses: []common.Address{
    contractAddress,
  },
}
```

That code, create a FilterQuery for the block number 133420. And them, you could use in FilterLogs function. Something like this:

```
logs, err := client.FilterLogs(context.Background(), query)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

**(Update)**

I saw the source code and test with rpc call and etherscan API.

**Source Code:**

// FilterQuery
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/filters/api.go

FilterQuery use NewRangeFilter:

// NewRangeFilter 
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/filters/filter.go

That use filter function:

```
/ Logs searches the blockchain for matching log entries, returning all from the
// first block that contains matches, updating the start of the filter accordingly.
func (f *Filter) Logs(ctx context.Context) ([]*types.Log, error) {
```

**Ways to try**

With your posted code!

**Test with etherscan api**

Call:

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=logs&action=getLogs&fromBlock=3997264&toBlock=3997264&address=0x6090a6e47849629b7245dfa1ca21d94cd15878ef&topic0=0x0f0c27adfd84b60b6f456b0e87cdccb1e5fb9603991588d87fa99f5b6b61e670&apikey=49W852FPN57GP4S3DR351SBKFYUP1N9TDD

Result:

```
{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":[{"address":"0x6090a6e47849629b7245dfa1ca21d94cd15878ef","topics":["0x0f0c27adfd84b60b6f456b0e87cdccb1e5fb9603991588d87fa99f5b6b61e670","0x4981ae698e550a328ba9008e83467cf24b3ab26163ae47bad5d0d109a717fc45","0x0000000000000000000000003fb14ab42b18736fc4b3ec9f88b80fe5829527fb"],"data":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005961c025","blockNumber":"0x3cfe50","timeStamp":"0x5961e543","gasPrice":"0x4dcfa4e5a","gasUsed":"0x1860f","logIndex":"0x1d","transactionHash":"0x05712456eca3acb77a524960757240088af05f0ddb2a4fb2a7cd6d8fb2a8880f","transactionIndex":"0x1f"},{"address":"0x6090a6e47849629b7245dfa1ca21d94cd15878ef","topics":["0x0f0c27adfd84b60b6f456b0e87cdccb1e5fb9603991588d87fa99f5b6b61e670","0x7d4646bbc88eccd949cb3aeed6da58f399c61f33beaa210d19dc535f2485801a","0x00000000000000000000000022786eb851d2172bbf8145e0f9a31d217ef19521"],"data":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005948d62a","blockNumber":"0x3cfe50","timeStamp":"0x5961e543","gasPrice":"0x4dcfa4e5a","gasUsed":"0x1864f","logIndex":"0x20","transactionHash":"0x085805dcf58263e9b3f78dfcb3fcfc2fdabd664a40040bf0d40870e846d5f57c","transactionIndex":"0x22"}]}
```

**Test with web3 filter (a wrapper to RPC API, "eth.filter" end using the same filter than logFilters )**

```
// block: 3997264 / https://etherscan.io/block/3997264
geth attach --exec 'var logs = []; var filter = web3.eth.filter({ fromBlock: "0x3cfe50", toBlock: "0x3cfe50", address: "0x6090a6e47849629b7245dfa1ca21d94cd15878ef", topics: ["0x0f0c27adfd84b60b6f456b0e87cdccb1e5fb9603991588d87fa99f5b6b61e670", null, null]}); filter.get(function(error, result){ logs.push(result) }); logs' ~/.ethereum/rinkeby/geth.ipc
```

Expect to get the following log entry back (from https://etherscan.io/tx/0x05712456eca3acb77a524960757240088af05f0ddb2a4fb2a7cd6d8fb2a8880f).

```
[{'address': '0x6090a6e47849629b7245dfa1ca21d94cd15878ef',
  'blockHash': '0x3f4d8282bcdd2d2637ada6693ac8f2df498475223c2626ca33a16eb56f74e2e0',
  'blockNumber': '0x3cfe50',
  'data': '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005961c025',
  'logIndex': '0x1d',
  'removed': False,
  'topics': ['0x0f0c27adfd84b60b6f456b0e87cdccb1e5fb9603991588d87fa99f5b6b61e670',
   '0x4981ae698e550a328ba9008e83467cf24b3ab26163ae47bad5d0d109a717fc45',
   '0x0000000000000000000000003fb14ab42b18736fc4b3ec9f88b80fe5829527fb'],
  'transactionHash': '0x05712456eca3acb77a524960757240088af05f0ddb2a4fb2a7cd6d8fb2a8880f',
  'transactionIndex': '0x1f'},
 {'address': '0x6090a6e47849629b7245dfa1ca21d94cd15878ef',
  'blockHash': '0x3f4d8282bcdd2d2637ada6693ac8f2df498475223c2626ca33a16eb56f74e2e0',
  'blockNumber': '0x3cfe50',
  'data': '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005948d62a',
  'logIndex': '0x20',
  'removed': False,
  'topics': ['0x0f0c27adfd84b60b6f456b0e87cdccb1e5fb9603991588d87fa99f5b6b61e670',
   '0x7d4646bbc88eccd949cb3aeed6da58f399c61f33beaa210d19dc535f2485801a',
   '0x00000000000000000000000022786eb851d2172bbf8145e0f9a31d217ef19521'],
  'transactionHash': '0x085805dcf58263e9b3f78dfcb3fcfc2fdabd664a40040bf0d40870e846d5f57c',
  'transactionIndex': '0x22'}]
```

Test with rpc call
doc: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getfilterlogs

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getFilterLogs","params":["0x16"],"id":74}' https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/YOURAPIKEY
```

Comment: That experiment doesn't demonstrate whether the ToBlock parameter is inclusive. I'd expect the FromBlock to be inclusive however.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: The key was to make FromBlock and ToBlock different values and verify that each block was read. Thanks for getting me started, but the web3 / etherscan stuff is getting further away from geth.

Comment: Also please make sure to remove your API key from the answer and probably regenerate a new one :)

Comment: Yes the api key was only for test and with a new user. Already deleted.

Comment: although testing the etherscan link still working ... weird ...